# Get all unique years from a date column using SQL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with a datetime column named 'created' which contains the date and time the record was inserted. This table has about 30 records right now. I want to get all occuring years (unique, not per record) from this table. Is there a way to do this using a MySQL query?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(created) FROM table
```

Answer (score 3):

Something on these lines should work (Warning: untested code ahead)

```
select year(created) as year, count(*) as count from table_name group by year
```

This will also give number of records for each year.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year from created) as year
FROM your_table
GROUP BY year
```

should work :)

Answer (score 2):

SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(Date) AS MYR
FROM            YOUR_DBF_HERE
ORDER BY MYR

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
EXTRACT(year from your_column_name) as MYEAR from your_table_name
group by EXTRACT(year from your_column_name)
```

The above worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

```
tableName::whereNotNull('columnName')->distinct()->get([DB::raw('YEAR(columnName) as year')]);
```

This is select distinct year from a date column in **laravel**.
I added **whereNotNull** because in my database the date is not a requirement.